# LED dot matrix connection problem with esp32

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

this marks my inaugural post on this platform.

I'm currently in the process of interfacing a 320x160 mm LED dot matrix with P4, of 80X40 RGB pixels, to an ESP32.

While I've successfully established the necessary connections and achieved an image, I've encountered a challenge. The displayed image appears segmented into bands instead of utilizing the entire screen as a cohesive unit. The issue is evident in the provided image, where, upon downward movement, the second word "hello" gets truncated. It seems that I'm restricted to using bands of 10 pixels in height.

Based on my research, I suspect this problem stems from the scanning mechanism, specifically a 1/10 screen division. It appears that the current library I'm utilizing may not be effectively managing this aspect.

Could this be the root cause and if so, what steps can I take to fix this? Do you know another library that allows me to control this screen? I appreciate your help in advance.

I leave the url of the bookstore I am using [Library](https://github.com/2dom/PxMatrix/tree/master)

[image shown on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdToD.jpg)

I made direct modifications to the scan settings in the code, setting it to 1/10. In this scenario, I observed that the behavior is similar to what it would have with a 1/16 scan, I was not able to obtain positive results.

I've explored alternatives and looked at other libraries, but it seems they all use 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, and 1/32 scans.

Comment: “I made direct modifications to the scan settings in the code”, we have no idea what you modified unless you provide your code.